# What version of the Facebook APIs does Social.framework and Accounts.framework use?

Tags: ios, facebook, social-framework, accounts-framework

I believe that iOS Social.framework directly uses the Facebook APIs. However, it is not clear what version of the Facebook APIs it is using. [Facebook will be discontinuing support for the v1 APIs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog), that is, [after April 30, 2015 the behavior when using the v1 APIs will be the same as the v2 APIs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading). This means that there are potential semantic changes in using the Social.framework APIs if it is using the v1 Facebook APIs.

Comment: I previously wrote up [a version of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892684/will-social-framework-stop-working-after-april-30-2015), but it was marked as a duplicate. I hope this version clarifies what I'm asking.